# g++ setting proper @rpath when building SFML

Tags: macos, open-source, gcc, darwin, dynamic-library

I'm trying to build an SFML sample without xcode (for reasons :-)).

The prebuilt samples comes with:

```
pong> otool -L pong
pong:
    @rpath/sfml-audio.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-audio (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
    @rpath/sfml-graphics.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-graphics (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
    @rpath/sfml-window.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-window (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
    @rpath/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-system (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 19.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

When I build it myself (build command follows), I rather obtain:

```
pong> otool -L a.out
a.out:
    @rpath/libsfml-system.2.5.dylib (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
    @rpath/libsfml-window.2.5.dylib (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
    @rpath/libsfml-graphics.2.5.dylib (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
    @rpath/libsfml-audio.2.5.dylib (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1300.36.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1319.0.0)
```

This prevents my built version from running, as it fails to load the library. How would I tell `g++` to generate the same `@rpath`s as those prebuilt?

The build command I used is:

```
g++ Pong.cpp -I ../../include -L ../../lib/ -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio
```

In case this makes any difference, this is on Ventura.

Comment: You need to link with Frameworks not just libraries - probaly look at doing this in Xcode and use clang not gnu cc